# No matching function for call to "BubbleSort"

Tags: c++, parameters, parameter-passing, bubble-sort

Hello I am having an error problem "No matching function for call to "BubbleSort". I'm creating a BubbleSort program with no classes. The parameters in my BubbleSort match the function call in main so I am not sure why I am getting this error. Any ideas?

**My main looks like this:**

```
int main()
{
int size = 5000;

int* array = CreateAnArray(size);

BubbleSort(array, size, comparison, itemAssignment);  ///This is where the error is 
}
```

**and the BubbleSort function looks like this:**

```
int BubbleSort(int* array, int size, int comparison, int itemAssignment)
{
bool done = false;
while (!done) {
    done = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            done = false;
            comparison++;
            Swap(array, i, i + 1);   
        }
        else
        {
            itemAssignment++;
        }  
    }
}
cout << "Number of comparisons: " << comparison << "Item Assignments: " << endl;
return comparison;
return itemAssignment;
}
```

*************My whole code***********

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int* CreateAnArray(int size) {
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int* array = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i <size; i++) {
        int randomnum = 1 + rand() % 100;
        array[i] = randomnum;
    }
    return array;
}

void Swap(int* array, int a, int b)
{
    int tmp = array[a];
    array[a] = array[b];
    array[b] = tmp;
}

int BubbleSort(int* array, int size, int comparison, int itemAssignment)
{
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        done = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                done = false;
                comparison++;

                Swap(array, i, i + 1);   
            }
            else
            {
                itemAssignment++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of comparisons: " << comparison << "Item Assignments: " << endl;
    return comparison;
    return itemAssignment;
    }

int get_comparison(int comparison){

    return comparison;
}

int get_itemAssignment(int itemAssignment){
    return itemAssignment;
}


int main()
{
    int size = 5000;
    int* array = CreateAnArray(size);

    BubbleSort(array, size, comparison, itemAssignment);       
}
```

Comment: What are `get_comparison` and `get_itemAssignment`? If they are functions instead of `int`'s then that's your problem. If they are anything other than a type `int` that's a problem. I state this in a couple of different ways because your arguments do _not_ match and you're already ignoring compiler errors. To reiterate, your parameters match but your arguments do not.

Comment: Is BubbleSort in the same file? Different file? Can you just post your entire code?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I created get_comparison and get_itemAssignment to get the value of the counters comparison and itemAssignment since a void function cannot return values. Should I try something different? I am new to C++

Comment: @Barry Yes it is, but I just pasted my whole code for you

Comment: Ok so you are trying to pass functions as integers? Not. Going. To.  Happen. Successfully.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I changed them to comparison and itemAssignment 

BubbleSort(array, size, comparison, itemAssignment);  

and error - "use of undeclared identifier 'comparison' " pops up? But it matches the other Bubblesort @CaptainObvlious

Comment: I can't see a def of "comparison"

Comment: Your `BubbleSort` function should probably take `comparison` and `itemAssignment` as references to a type `int` based on your implementation. This means you needs to pass non-const `int` variables to the function instead of functions (pointers to functions). I'm hesitant to post a solution since even your code is totally confused :)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious At this moment my answer is right. The "comparison" lacks definition

Comment: @AB_ Well whoop-dee-doo :)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious whoop-dee-do? ;p

Comment: Thank you all for your help. @CaptainObvlious you were right! I needed to set comparison = 0 and itemAssignments = 0. I defined it both in the BubbleSort function and the main. And thank you for not posting a solution..I need to learn on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comparison in

```
BubbleSort(array, size, comparison, itemAssignment);
```

is undefined.

Comment: Thank you! That helped. I just needed to add int comparison = 0 and int itemAssignment = 0 for the counter!

Comment: if you just do int BubbleSort(int* array, int size, int comparison = 0, int itemAssignment = 0) then what you did is to set default values for those parameters. From now on you can call BubbleSort just with two arguments: BubbleSort( array, size) and values for omitted args are 0